# Can't set palette in bitmap

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, palette

I have been writing a PCX decoder and, so far, the PCX image itself parses fine, but I can't work out how to set the palette of a bitmap.

I have created a bitmap like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width,
                        height,
                        stride2,
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed,
                        pixels);
```

But I can't seem to set the palette using the following method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 3)
{
    Color b = new Color();
    b = Color.FromArgb(palette[i], palette[i + 1], palette[i + 2]);
    bmp.Palette.Entries.SetValue(b, i);
}
```

In this example, I have read through each byte in the palette of the pcx file and stored them in palette[]. from there, I have used this to set the entries in the palette of the bitmap. How do I set the colours?

Answer (score 37):

This had me confused too. It seems bitmap.Palette returns a clone of the bitmap's palette. Once you've modified your copy, you need to reset the bitmap's pallete by using `bitmap.Palette = palette`, e.g.

```
ColorPalette palette = bitmap.Palette;
palette.Entries[i] = new Color(...);
....
bitmap.Palette = palette; // The crucial statement
```

See http://www.charlespetzold.com/pwcs/PaletteChange.html

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, it returns a clone, it is the only explanation I know.

Answer (score 13):

According to [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs), `Palette` property of `Image` class in .net, internally uses GDI+ Flat APIs for handling palettes. `GdipGetImagePalette` used for initializing `ColorPalette` object in `get` method and `GdipSetImagePalette` used for writing `ColorPalette` object data back to device is `set` method.

Each time in your `for` loop the line `bmp.Palette.Entries.SetValue(b, i);` forces the Image to call `GdipGetImagePalette` and data of `bmp.Palette` reinitialized and therefore you can see no change has been made to `bmp.Palette` after the loop.

To solve this problem you must do the following:

1. Assign new alias to `bmp.Palette` by assigning it to a variable,
2. Modify it by new alias (this prevents reloading),
3. And put it back to the `bmp.Palette`.

Code:

```
var newAliasForPalette = bmp.Palette; // Palette loaded from graphic device
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    newAliasForPalette.Entries[i] = myColor[i];
}
bmp.Palette = newAliasForPalette; // Palette data wrote back to the graphic device
```

In my opinion, replacement of definition of `Palette` as a property with `GetPalette()` and `SetPalette()` methods by Microsoft, will be a great help in avoiding confusion.